# Dart doesn't save cookies from previous request

Tags: cookies, angular, dart

I need to do one request to take a session from server. Now I included it in the same `POST` request (this play no role) with authorization header. I successfully get a valid session by `OPTIONS` request from my Tomcat server in response cookies. Like this: JSESSION:XXXXX .
After I make main `POST` request with photos etc. And response is `401 Unauthorized`. I looked in Chrome developers panel. Request cookies are empty. So I understood, that dart didn't save cookies. With this param in request: `withCredentials: true` on every request I'm getting a popup. I use Angular2 in my project. (I said it because, in Angular2 can be solution for my problem)
Dart code:

```
map["Authorization"] = "Basic YWRtaW5hZG1pbjphbm90aGVyY29vbA==";
await HttpRequest.request("http://localhost:8080/photo", method: "POST",withCredentials: true, sendData: formData, requestHeaders:map)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Dart doesn't have anything to do with it. This is an issue between server and browser. What you you mean by `OPTIONS` request. You normally don't send and `OPTIONS` request yourself, they are normally created automatically by the browser and sent as preflight requests.

Cookies passed by the server are automatically sent back by the browser with each request.

Comment: I mean, that requests from dart don't contain cookies inside

Comment: I know, but I still don't think it is related to Dart. If the server sets the cookie correctly the browser sends it back automatically.